# TestNG - methos should be used as test count

Tags: java, jenkins, testng

I run testNG in jenkins.  I have many tests classes crate and run around 100 tests, But problem i see is in jenskin it is a graph "test count 1" but i would like to have 100 tests. My file is below:

```
<suite name="Smoke ALL Parallel" parallel="classes" thread-count="1">
  <test name="Smoke Tests">
    <parameter name="url" value="https://${choose_hostname}"/>
    <parameter name="browser" value="${choose_browser}"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="BO.UnitTests.Smoke_Home"/>
      <class name="BO.UnitTests.Smoke_Users"/>
      <class name="BO.UnitTests.Smoke_Invoices"/>
      <class name="BO.UnitTests.Smoke_Managment"/>
     </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Jenkins:
[image: Jenskins TestNG green TestCases=1]

Test report for TestNG:
[image: Test in details]

The question is how my methods in classes are represented as Test in TestNG report.
It should be same as in Junit or mbunit in .net wher eeach method represent test. all test represent total tests.

Thank you for all support.

Regards,
Dani

Comment: Each test method that is run adds one to the count of methods as reported in Jenkins. a) You might not have each method annotated with `@Test`. b) Only one method being run. c) All other methods might be skipped. In other words, you didn't show us the important stuff.

Comment: each test mehod has @Test before name, see added picture for tests in main comment

Comment: Can you share your testng config of the jenkins setup..what file are you referring to there.

Comment: It was solved by our CM in company . Thank you for your time.